# SEM or CFA for two level structure

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I have 20 observed factors and I want to check their validaty as a scale of 4 latent variables. For this purpose I should use the cfa function. Right?

Then I want also to check a second order model. Its structure is as follows: these 20 observed factors load on these 4 latent variables which consist 2 larger latent variables. Should I have to use the sem function for the second scenario? I'm using R studio and here is my code

```
MYMODEL='V1=~ Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4 
V2=~ Q5 + Q6 + Q7 +Q8+Q9 
V3=~ Q10 + Q11 + Q12 + Q13 + Q14+ Q15 
V4=~Q16+Q17+Q18+Q19+Q20 
LB1=~V1+V2 
LB2=~V3+V4' 
MYMODEL.fit=sem(MYMODEL,data=MYDATA,missing="listwise", ordered = TRUE,estimator="WLSMV") 
fitMeasures(MYMODEL.fit)
```

where Q... are the observed variables,
V...are the first order latent variables and 
LB...the second order latent variables.

Comment: By two-level do you mean multilevel, or hierarchical? Can you post model syntax or a path diagram?

Comment: Also, what package are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I mean two level SEM, its not hierarchical. I'm using R.

Comment: MYMODEL='V1=~ Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4 
V2=~ Q5 + Q6 + Q7 +Q8+Q9
V3=~ Q10 + Q11 + Q12 + Q13 + Q14+ Q15
V4=~Q16+Q17+Q18+Q19+Q20
LB1=~V1+V2
LB2=~V3+V4'
MYMODEL.fit=sem(MYMODEL,data=MYDATA,missing="listwise", ordered = TRUE,estimator="WLSMV")
fitMeasures(MYMODEL.fit)
where Q... are the observed variables, V...are the first level latent variables and LB...the second level latent variables. Is this correct?

Comment: Maybe it is more clear to use the definition second order rather than two level.

Comment: Can you edit the question, rather than adding bits in the comments?

Comment: Oh sure, I'm sorry. I didn't see that I had this option. I edited the question. Could you help me please with the code? Is this correct?

Comment: it's very hard to read the code. Please edit the question  and (if you can) format the code.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CV. From the style of your code, it appears you are using the `lavaan`package for *R*. Note that while, in principle, there are some between CFA and SEM as **analyses**, the **functions** `cfa()` and `sem()`in the `lavaan` package do not offer different functionality--they are both wrappers for the more general `lavaan()` function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28241055/lavaan-cfa-vs-sem), for a related StacksOverflow question). You could fit your higher-order measurement model using the `cfa()` function, and it would be fine.